# Setting up SSIS Item Template in SQL Server Data Tools for Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, ssis, sql-server-2012

I have created a dtsx file to use as an SSIS package template. I want to be able to use the file as a template by clicking on an open Project in Solution Explorer and selecting Add -> New Item

My questions are:

- How do I save this as a template file?  Its currently a .dtsx file.
- Where do I have to place the file so its in my list of options in the Add New Items dialog?  I have seen many conflicting paths and none specifically for SQL Server Data Tools for Visual Studio 2012.

[image: Add New Item Dialog]

I have searched for instructions on how to do this but have now found clear instructions for use with SQL Server Data Tools for Visual Studio 2012.  Posts I have found are conflicting and don't clearly explain how convert the dtsx file into a template file.  The link [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ms247113(v=vs.71)) is an example of conflicting info; its posted for vs 2010 and examples are for vs 2005.  I have also tried to use the [Export Template Wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ff527343(v=vs.71)) but this feature seems to have gone away in SSDT for VS2012.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to copy the dtsx package to following location and restart the SSDT for VS2012.  Note that the VS installation location may be different in your machine. 
First select the package that you want to export as a template and then Select File->Save  As.. 
and save it to

**C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\ProjectItems\DataTransformationProject\DataTransformationItems**

E.g. 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\ProjectItems\DataTransformationProject\DataTransformationItems\MyTemplatePackage.dtsx

*Quote: I have also tried to use the Export Template Wizard but this feature seems to have gone away in SSDT for VS2012*

SSDT for VS2012 does not have an export template wizard. It's only avaible for VS2012.